# SSRS report not displaying data in pdf

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ifs

For particular site say 213,data is not displaying in pdf. But for other site data is displaying in pdf. for 213, sql query returns the result but not in pdf..

**Input parameter is result key**. Please explain why this happening?

Comment: Is the data showing ok if you just run it as a query for 213?

Comment: for site 213, sql query return the result not in pdf or xml while export.

Comment: @Harry for 213, query return a row.